# Display vector points in MapBox from S3

Tags: geojson, vector, ogr2ogr, mapbox, tippecanoe

I have a shapefile with around 14 millions points that I want to display in MapBox on a web application. The only documentation around displaying points I can see is by using MapBox tiling service, though I want to host this in S3. I have had little problem creating a tilesets from raster files and retrieving them from S3 like this:

```
this.map.addSource(l, {
    "type": "raster",
    "tiles": [`https://<my-url>/{z}/{x}/{y}.png`],
});
this.map.addLayer({
    "id": l,
    "type": "raster",
    "source": l,
});
```

To achieve similar with the vector tiles I have done:

```
this.map.addLayer({
    "id": "l",
    "type": "circle",
    "source": {
        "type": "vector",
        "tiles": ["https://<my-url>/{z}/{x}/{y}.pbf"],
    },
    "source-layer": "l",
});
```

to prepare the PBF files I: converted shp to GeoJSON with GeoPandas; used tippecanoe to convert from GeoJSON to mbtiles; used ogr2ogr to convert mbtiles to PBF directories. I then put these in S3.

When I go to the points in MapBox (with 10 sample points), I get this error:

> Error {message: 'Unimplemented type: 3'}

from MapBox.

What am I doing wrong? Have I prepared the PBF files incorrectly or am I missing something in my code configuring the retrieval of the files?

Comment: See https://github.com/mapbox/tippecanoe/issues/582.

Comment: thank you @TomazicM, that seems to point me in the right direction. Do you know if I need to change the way S3 serves the files, or am I meant to parse them when consuming in mapbox?

Comment: I'm not familiar with S3, but anyway the safest way would be to create .pbf tiles non compressed, using `--no-tile-compression` switch for `tippecanoe`.

Comment: No luck unfortunately. I tried setting the content type of the objects in S3 as suggested but I am still getting the errors. I will try a different way